# How to render a collection of Components after mapping them in React

Tags: reactjs

I´m new in React, I get this error:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

When I try to render a collection of Components by mapping them from an Array.

Ive read many threads about this topic but I cannot figure out whats wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance!

```
function ItemPage({items}) {
    return (
    <ul> 
    {
        items.map((item) => 
            <li key={item.id}> 
                <Item title={item.name} /> 
            </li> 
        ) 

    }
    </ul> 
    ); 
}
```

This is the items array:

```
let items = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Apple iPad Mini 2 16GB",
    description: "An iPad like no other. 16GB, WiFi, 4G.",
    price: 229.00
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Apple iPad Mini 2 32GB",
    description: "Even larger than the 16GB.",
    price: 279.00
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canon T7i",
    description: "DSLR camera with lots of megapixels.",
    price: 749.99
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Apple Watch Sport",
    description: "A watch",
    price: 249.99
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Apple Watch Silver",
    description: "A more expensive watch",
    price: 599.99
}
];
```

Comment: can you give a sample for `items`? can `item.id` may not be a string or number?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this code. I would have to guess the error is either in `<Item/>` or in the passed array `items`.

Comment: I added the list of items

Comment: the snippets you gave seems to be working fine, something else might be wrong: https://codesandbox.io/s/5w5o0o1o4p

Comment: Thank you guys I figured out my problem I was getting obssesed with the wrong piece of code, I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not within your posted code. Run the snippet below to see your code functioning. The only thing I added that isn't in your code, is the definition for the `<Item/>` component, so perhaps that is where your issue is.

```js
function Item({title}){
  return (<span>{title}</span>);
}

function ItemPage({items}) {
    return (
    <ul> 
    {
        items.map((item) => 
            <li key={item.id}> 
                <Item title={item.name} /> 
            </li> 
        ) 

    }
    </ul> 
    ); 
} 

let items = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Apple iPad Mini 2 16GB",
    description: "An iPad like no other. 16GB, WiFi, 4G.",
    price: 229.00
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Apple iPad Mini 2 32GB",
    description: "Even larger than the 16GB.",
    price: 279.00
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Canon T7i",
    description: "DSLR camera with lots of megapixels.",
    price: 749.99
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Apple Watch Sport",
    description: "A watch",
    price: 249.99
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Apple Watch Silver",
    description: "A more expensive watch",
    price: 599.99
}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <ItemPage items={items}/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I solved it, thank you for your help!! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what was wrong with my code, the problem was not in the definition of the Component 'ItemPage' but in the definition of Item

I had the following

```
const Item = (props,children) =>{
return (
<div className="item">
    <div className="left">

        <ItemImage/>

        <div className="imageDescription">
            <ItemTitle title={props.title}/>
            <ItemDescription description={props.description}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
        <ItemPrice price={props.price}/>
            {children}
    </div>

</div>

);}
```

I changed the params that the function received for only props and It worked fine.

```
const Item = (props) =>{
return (
<div className="item">
    <div className="left">

        <ItemImage/>

        <div className="imageDescription">
            <ItemTitle title={props.title}/>
            <ItemDescription description={props.description}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
        <ItemPrice price={props.price}/>
            {props.children}
    </div>

</div>

);}
```